# How to find sum of arrays in a column which is grouped by another column values in a spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` like below

> ```
> c1             Value
> A             Array[47,97,33,94,6]
> A             Array[59,98,24,83,3]
> A             Array[77,63,93,86,62]
> B             Array[86,71,72,23,27]
> B             Array[74,69,72,93,7]
> B             Array[58,99,90,93,41]
> C             Array[40,13,85,75,90]
> C             Array[39,13,33,29,14]
> C             Array[99,88,57,69,49]
> ```

I need an output as below.

```
c1             Value
A             Array[183,258,150,263,71]
B             Array[218,239,234,209,75]
C             Array[178,114,175,173,153]
```

Which is nothing but grouping **column** c1 and find the sum of values in **column** value in a sequential manner . 
Please help, I couldn't find any way of doing this in google .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very complicated. As you mention it, you can simply group by "c1" and aggregate the values of the array index by index.

Let's first generate some data:

```scala
val df = spark.range(6)
    .select('id % 3 as "c1",
            array((1 to 5).map(_ => floor(rand * 10)) : _*) as "Value")
df.show()
+---+---------------+
| c1|          Value|
+---+---------------+
|  0|[7, 4, 7, 4, 0]|
|  1|[3, 3, 2, 8, 5]|
|  2|[2, 1, 0, 4, 4]|
|  0|[0, 4, 2, 1, 8]|
|  1|[1, 5, 7, 4, 3]|
|  2|[2, 5, 0, 2, 2]|
+---+---------------+
```

Then we need to iterate over the values of the array so as to aggregate them. It is very similar to the way we created them:

```scala
val n = 5 // if you know the size of the array
val n = df.select(size('Value)).first.getAs[Int](0) // If you do not
df
    .groupBy("c1")
    .agg(array((0 until n).map(i => sum(col("Value").getItem(i))) :_* ) as "Value")
    .show()
+---+------------------+
| c1|             Value|
+---+------------------+
|  0|[11, 18, 15, 8, 9]|
|  1|  [2, 10, 5, 7, 4]|
|  2|[7, 14, 15, 10, 4]|
+---+------------------+
```